# QGIS 3.16.5 v.distance returns UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, unicodedecodeerror

I'm trying to run v.distance on QGIS but get the following message/s:

```
2021-04-14T17:45:55     CRITICAL    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.16/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\algs\grass7\Grass7Algorithm.py", line 434, in processAlgorithm
  Grass7Utils.executeGrass(self.commands, feedback, self.outputCommands)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.16/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\algs\grass7\Grass7Utils.py", line 398, in executeGrass
  for line in iter(proc.stdout.readline, ''):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.16\apps\Python37\lib\encodings\cp1255.py", line 23, in decode
  return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
 UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8c in position 113: character maps to
```

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8c in position
> 113: character maps to

I have had problems with GRASS with a non ASCII charachter (like ö) in the path. Try changing it.